# Implementing static id generation for adempiere zk web ui framework

Tags: java, zk, adempiere

How to implement static id generation for adempiere zk? The default staticidgenerator.java is not working properly. How can we implement static id generation for adempiere

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an apache commons library: http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-id/